# Passing GO pointers to C callback function

Tags: pointers, go, cgo

I have a requirement to pass a function pointer as a parameter (ie, a callback function)  to a C function inside a shared object.  The expectation is to get a callback from the function inside the shared object. I need to implement the function in GO and should be invoked as a callback from C shared object. My solution is throwing a Segmentation fault in the last step.

```
//////////////in libcshared.so ///////////
typedef void (*test_function_ptr)(int a)
void callerfun(test_function_ptr callback)

//////////////in GO program//////C program
void* gofunptr;
void implfun(int x){
GOSharedfn(gofunptr);
}
-------------
func main(){
C.gofunptr = &gofun
var callback = C.test_function_ptr(unsafe.Pointer(C.implfun))
C.callerfun(callback )
}
var gofun = goimpl
func goimpl(){
}
/////////GO shared lib libgoshared.so/////////<br>
func GOSharedfn(unsafe.Pointer pointer){
f:=(cast to fun ptr)pointer
f();//Segmentation fault
}
```

[Function call flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRoxo.png)

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#function-variables? (and please format your code correctly, it's quite hard to read here)

Comment: Thanks Jim, this helped.